# How can this generator function be turned into a generator expression?

Tags: python, generator, python-itertools, generator-expression

I have written a generator function that yields an infinite sequence of strings in the same fashion as the column-naming scheme in a spreadsheet application like Excel, e.g.:

```
'', 'A', 'B', ... 'Z', 'AA', 'AB', ... 'AZ', 'BA', ... 'ZZ', 'AAA', ...
```

My function works without any issues:

```
def __suffix_generator():
    len, gen = (0, iter(['']))

    while True:
        try:
            suffix = next(gen)
        except StopIteration:
            len += 1
            gen = itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=len)
            suffix = next(gen)

        yield ''.join(suffix)
```

However, I want to turn it into a more idiomatic version which will use only generator expressions and my best shot so far is this:

```
def __suffix_generator_gexp():
    from itertools import product, count
    from string import ascii_uppercase

    return (''.join(suffix) for suffix in
        (product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=len) for len in count()))
```

When using that generator, I get a runtime TypeError which tells me that the type of the `suffix` variable isn't accepted:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, tuple found
```

My assumption is that `suffix` should be a tuple containing the letters of the particular combination and that `join` would turn that into a string. How can I get this to work correctly, just like the first function?

Comment: `join` will join a tuple of strings into a string. The error is saying that `suffix[0]` is a tuple, not a string,

Comment: FWIW, it is bad practice to assign values to built-ins. `len` is a built-in function in Python, and you're replacing it within that function's scope when you assign `0` to `len`. Using something like `length` instead might be preferable, yet close to the logic you're trying to convey using `len` currently.

Comment: @not_a_robot: thanks, these are my first attempts with Python and I didn't even suspect that a `len` built-in exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
map(''.join, chain.from_iterable(product(ascii_uppercase, repeat=l) for l in count(1)))
```

`count(n)` produces a sequence of numbers starting with `n` using `step = 1`, so that each number `N_{t+1} = N_t + step` and `N_1 = n`.

If you're using Python 2.x, `map` will attempt to construct a list and will fail, so you can just do:

```
(''.join(perm) for perm in (...))
```

Where `...` is the second argument of `map` from the first snippet.

Comment: Thank you! The second snippet worked nicely in Python 2.7.13.